# Scrape data from jsQuery into csv

Tags: javascript, python, csv

I practicing how to scrape with python (bs4). 
I want to scrape the names and all the geolocations on the googlemap of this website:
http://www.amsterdam-dance-event.nl/locations/festival/

Though I can manage to scrape the names from the html, I think it calls the geolocations from this jsquery: www.amsterdam-dance-event-.nl/min/en-desktop/20150903115044.js:965

Therefore I do not know what to do. Please help

Comment: Try with Node.js/PhantomJS/CasperJs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use a scraping/automating framework which supports Javascript, [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/installation.html#downloading-python-bindings-for-selenium), for example.